# Can we navigate from mobile app to mobile web and vice versa while scripting in monkey talk tool?

Tags: automation, recording, monkeytalk

I am automating my mobile application using monkey talk. But i also want to navigate from mobile app to web and vice versa so that i can also automate admin section of the mobile application while recording. In short i want to switch to and fro from mobile app to web and vice versa while recording the scenarios in monkey talk. Please assist ASAP

Thanks
Varun

Answer (score 1):

Since the MonkeyTalk Agent is part of your App, it can only find UIViews that are within your app's view hierarchy. Furthermore, once your app enters background, it will no longer receive http requests from the MonkeyTalk IDE or your test runner. **So recording or controlling something outside your app is not possible with MonkeyTalk.**

A (rather expensive) workaround could be to integrate a web view within your app. I haven't tried something like that, so I cannot say, if MonkeyTalk is able to identify elements within the web page inside a UIWebView.